# IBM WCM textboxio modify toolbar

Tags: ibm-wcm, textboxio

I am using the Textboxio editor within WCM 8.5 installed on CentOS 6.5

The official docs are skimpy http://docs.ephox.com/display/tbio/Changing+the+Toolbar

First question: I have successfully added new styles by editing tbio_config.jsp but now I need to add new options for ordered and unordered lists.  I think I have to modify

ui: {locale: locale, toolbar: {items : items }}

But how?

Second question: having successfully added new styles to the back-end content editor.  (Editing content from the libraries), I configured Textboxio as my inline editor.  But that does not show my new styles.  It must be using a different config, but I can't find where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, modifying the toolbar means setting the `items` property. There is an example of this (you don't need to set locale) towards the bottom of the article you linked; the section [Defining the toolbar configuration](http://docs.ephox.com/display/tbio/Changing+the+Toolbar#ChangingtheToolbar-Definingthetoolbarconfiguration). It contains the default editor config and links to the list of toolbar commands.

The inline editor may use a different configuration, I'm not sure. You'll have to ask IBM about that. However the inline editor ignores content CSS set in the configuration (a warning about this will appear in the console if it is set). By definition this editor mode uses the content styles already defined for the page; you can still adjust the style menu through the configuration but not the content styles.

Comment: Ok so looking at the ref 
http://docs.ephox.com/display/tbio/Command+Item+IDs
I see that I need Group ID of listindent and Command ID of ul, but how do I add my own option to that Command ID?

Comment: ah, I didn't realise that's what you were trying to do. Sorry, we don't support customising those menus at the moment.

Feel free to log a feature request at http://support.ephox.com and we'll pass it on to our product manager.